# Unable to compile caide-cpp-inliner

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm, mingw-w64

I need a tool for dead-code elimination in C++.

- [caide-cpp-inliner](https://github.com/slycelote/caide-cpp-inliner)

So, I cloned the full Git repository along with `llvm-project`, and I am trying to compile **Caide** using CLion and MSYS2 MinGW64.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
====================[ Clean | Debug ]===========================================
"C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\git\caide-cpp-inliner\cmake-build-debug --target clean -j 3
[1/1] Cleaning all built files...
Cleaning... 2 files.

Clean finished

====================[ Build | caide_cpp_inliner | Debug ]=======================
"C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\git\caide-cpp-inliner\cmake-build-debug --target caide_cpp_inliner -j 3
[1/97] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/caide_cpp_inliner.dir/doc/demo/ascii_graphics.cpp.obj
[2/97] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/caide_cpp_inliner.dir/src/clang_compat.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/caide_cpp_inliner.dir/src/clang_compat.cpp.obj 
"C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1.3\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe"  -IC:/git/caide-cpp-inliner/src -IC:/git/caide-cpp-inliner/tests/cases/include-option-std/mystd -IC:/git/caide-cpp-inliner/tests/cases/inliner2/user-inc -IC:/git/caide-cpp-inliner/tests/cases/pull-headers-up/mystd -IC:/git/caide-cpp-inliner/tests/cases/std-namespace/mystd -g -std=gnu++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/caide_cpp_inliner.dir/src/clang_compat.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\caide_cpp_inliner.dir\src\clang_compat.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/caide_cpp_inliner.dir/src/clang_compat.cpp.obj -c C:/git/caide-cpp-inliner/src/clang_compat.cpp
In file included from C:/git/caide-cpp-inliner/src/clang_compat.cpp:7:
C:/git/caide-cpp-inliner/src/clang_compat.h:9:10: fatal error: clang/Basic/SourceLocation.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <clang/Basic/SourceLocation.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[3/97] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/caide_cpp_inliner.dir/doc/demo/main.cpp.obj
[4/97] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/caide_cpp_inliner.dir/src/caideInliner.cpp.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

How can I fix it?

```
c:\>clang --version
clang version 16.0.4
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin

c:\>
```

Comment: You have a whole bunch of `-I` directives for finding caide includes, but none for locating clang.